# Count Search Results Per Query Response in Solr

Tags: apache, solr

Is it possible to count search results per query response in solr? I did it by highlighting query responses by  tags and counting them but when query consists of two words (for example "this afternoon") solr highlights each word separately (*this* *aftarnoon*) so counting  tags results in wrong response.

Comment: solr response does give the total count. which count are you expecting? can you explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

SOLR Provides 'numFound' in result
Ex: If your Query is`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true`
u will get a response as

```
"response":{"numFound":6,"start":0,"docs":[
  { 
     // field values
  }]
```

}

**"numFound":6** in response is the total count of results in response.

Answer (score 0):

Response from solr contains:

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1314,
    ...
}
```

where numFound is the total count of matched results.

In solrj you can extract it with:

```
queryResponse.getResults().getNumFound();
```

or only returned results with:

```
queryResponse.getResults().size();
```